# calculate the memory space allocated by a structure in C

Tags: c, memory, trie

I would like to know if there is a way to calculate the memory space before and after a certain function call or a program... something like the time stamp to calculate the execution time...

I'm asking this because I want to test the performance of my code regarding memory space because I'm using a `tree` data structure... and I need to present in my defense the performance of my project regarding certain aspects...

I'm using windows

Comment: Wrappers for `free`, `malloc`, etc. keeping track of allocations?

Comment: Did you try using valgrind?

Comment: what OS? The answer for your question would be OS specific, I think

Answer (score 4):

To figure out the bytes used by a structure named `foo`, you can use `sizeof(struct foo)`.

POSIX.1 says you can call [getrusage()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrusage.html) to find out how much memory you are using.

Many C implementations will let you call [sbrk(0)](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_669.html) to get the current "top of memory" address.

On Windows, you can use [GetProcessMemoryInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Other platforms may have other calls similar to these, but if all else fails, you can wrap `malloc()` and `free()` with versions that keep track of the data usage that you're interested in keeping track of.

Comment: what I understood is that if I used the GetProcessMemoryInfo() before my function and then after my function execution then I'll know how much memory my function used ?

Comment: if I wrote memory=sizeof(t); 
memory will have 12 as value

t is of type struct 
typedef struct
{
  int size;
  int num_nodes;   // number of nodes in the trie
  trie_node *root;
}trie;

and size inside t will have value of 4578

this is the 
int trie_create(trie *t)
{
  memset(t, '\0', sizeof(trie));
  return trie_SUCCESS;
}

Comment: It might have twelve; on a 32-bit platform it probably will be, but on a 64-bit platform it won't be. Using sizeof() in counters for your `trie_create()` function though is portable and probably what you want.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably going to be platform/compiler specific. In unix/Linux/etc, you can use `sbrk(0)` to find the *end* of memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    char *start, *data, *end;
    start = sbrk(0);
    printf("%p\n", start);
    data = malloc(243);
    end = sbrk(0);
    printf("%p\n", end);
    printf("diff: %ld", (long)(end - start));
    return 0;
}
```

Output (Cygwin):

```
0x80020000
0x80050000
diff: 196608
```